# How to implement facebook like button within Handlebars template?

Tags: facebook, templates, facebook-like, handlebars.js

fb js sdk FB.init is already executed in index.php before navigating to the following template page.

LikeGate.hbs

```
<section class="likeGate">
    <p>Please Like the page to continue</p>
    blah<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Test/foo?sk=bar" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please clarify your question by providing your entire code and telling us what goes wrong with it?

Comment: Solved: FB.XFBML.parse() at anytime after injecting a template to re-parse all of the XFBML on a page